# Xamarin.Forms - Deploy via e-mail giving me fits

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I made a nice (aren't they all) app using VS 2013, debugged, tested etc. without much fuss and muss.

Now I want to pass it out to some friends for reality check, and so used the `VS2015.Tools.Android.Publish Android App...` feature.

I followed the instructions, got a Release build signed APK (and a non-signed APK too). I e-mailed the signed APK to myself on the Motorola Razr Turbo, and installed just fine.

However, **it does not run**. It just flashes up then terminates. I have reviewed the Xamarin instructions and tried a number of things but I am blocked for now. This app runs fine on the same phone after I have deployed it during development (Release build as well as Debug).

I feel I am missing something obvious to all those who have traveled this path before, and really would appreciate a pointer to a happier place.

Comment: I seem to remember running into the same issue and it was because I wasn't signing it properly. Just to confirm, you have created a keystore and used that to sign the apk?

Comment: Yes, I did take those steps but properly is the key here; I will review the doc and do it again tonight. Sounds like the kind of thing it might be (I am also going to look at the zipalign business).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

I often have to uninstall the previous version of the app (the one deployed during debugging/development).

Also, if the app requires some special permissions, check that those are still allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, have given them both a whack to no avail. Actually I have the same problem with the Tasky application (not mine at all). I think I will make a little 'hello world' app just further limit the scope.

Comment: So, created a brand new Xamarin Forms app, did not touch a line of code. Builds and runs fine under the debugger (well, puts up the 'ole Welcome to Xamarin label). Build the Release version, went through the deploy steps, sent to myself via e-mail,  removed the Hello app from my phone, installed it just fine and ... same deal. 

Well. At least not my app. Makes me wonder if developers actually use this dev path (e-mail to friendlies for feedback) much. Of course, I did search here first to no avail ...

Comment: You could try plugging the phone in, running LogCat (there's a handy button in the Xamarin Visual Studio toolbar) and then launch the app.  That's how I originally tracked down some permissions issues.

Comment: LogCat is giving me  a toehold:

I/ActivityManager(  885): Start proc 20197:H.H/u0a258 for activity H.H/md5db3b528c0c7741926ecd7b82eb68de6a.MainActivity
W/monodroid(20197): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/H.H-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid-assembly(20197): Assembly 'assemblies/Hello.Droid.dll' is located at a bad address 0xa23b0bfd
F/monodroid-assembly(20197): You MUST run `zipalign` on base.apk
I/Zygote  (  447): Process 20197 exited cleanly (90)

Comment: So, off to run zipalign on base.apk (well, whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Ah yes, have to run the old zipalign on the signed package. Help here (thanks Nigel) took me to use LogCat, and there was the problem. Found some more help at:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4169/apk-no-longer-working-on-device

and put together a batch file to run it; one line:
"C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 ./bin/Release/MyFineApp.SoNice-Signed.apk ./WillRunNow.apk

Comment: While links aren't a problem in and of themselves, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: How true; I thought that I had done that, what with fingering the need to run zipalign and including the batch file line I used to fix the problem. Will be more clear next time; thanks for the assistance and edits too. I agree grammar is important!